# INDIRECT function returning #REF

Tags: excel, excel-indirect

My INDIRECT function is returning a `#REF!` error. I am wanting part of the formula to be dynamic, by referencing another cell:

```
=INDIRECT('I:\&"C1"&.xlsx'!Average)
```

With `C1` being a text value. The text is correct and references the file I need, but it seems to throw an error when I add `indirect` to it.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your quotation marks are wrong. Try this:

```
=INDIRECT("'I:\"&C1&".xlsx'!Average")
```

Assuming that in cell C1 you have a String that you want to be inserted in your indirection Formula.